# Django how to make internal api call?

Tags: python, django

Currently I'm using `requests` library to make an internal API call. But it fails on staging.

```
class LoginSubscriber(generics.GenericAPIView):
    queryset = User.objects.all()
    serializer_class = LoginSerializer
    client_id = settings.client_id
    client_secret = settings.client_secret

    def user_logged_in(self, username, password, host):
        data = [('grant_type', 'password'),
            ('username', username),
            ('password', password),
            ('scope', 'read')]
        return requests.post(self.protocol + host + '/oauth/token/', data=data, auth=(self.client_id, self.client_secret)) #


    def post(self, request):
        serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            data = serializer.data
            host = request.META['HTTP_HOST']
            logged_in_token = self.user_logged_in(request, data['username'],data['password'], host)
            if logged_in_token:
                return Response({'token': logged_in_token.text}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            return Response({'status': 'Failed Authentication'}, status=status.HTTP_401_UNAUTHORIZED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

Is there any way to achieve this without requests library?

Comment: Could you do whatever the view does for that URL there? Call it with a mocked request or call a similar helper function it does?

Comment: any sample code..

Comment: i assume you have a  handler/function accepts `post`ed data and does something with it and returns some response. why don't you pass the authorization data  to that function?

Comment: yeah, but I also want some extra data to get returned.

Comment: @AvinashRaj Hi, did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

If you used development server, which is single-threaded. It is processing in the original request,so  it's not possible to process the internal request for another URL.

you need to call with other port number.

Comment: why would you call on another port number when the server is running on a port number